# How to Change an Icon based on what Collider the Player Hits

Tags: unity, 2d, platform

So I have a 2D platform game where a player goes around collecting fruit but currently I only have one icon. Currently I use an image on a canvas to display the fruit image. How can I make the UI image change based on what fruit the player collects?

Comment: If we do not even know how you have your current one icon setup, we can't tell you how to change it to a different one.

Comment: I use an image on a canvas

Comment: Hi, like Zibelas also mentioned, could you provide a bit more details as to what the icon is used for and what you have tried so far? Without that, a lot is possible and a lot of guessing has to be done.

Comment: @D.Kallan I have an image of the fruit next to the score but I want the image to change dependingo n what fruit they collecy

Comment: Assuming the fruit itself has an image, when you pick it up, you can assign the sprite from the fruit's sprite-renderer to the sprite-renderer of your score icon, right? You might have to make the score icon accessible to the player / fruit (depending who detects the pickup) so that the one that detects/removes the fruit can say `scoreIcon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = fruit.sprite`, for example. Ofc you can also just store a reference to said sprite renderer, so you don't have the GetComponent<...>() every time. (dont store the whole thing if you only need one component)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make a simple data container to put on our fruit items. For now, this will contain just the image we want to display when we collect it.

```
public class Collectable : MonoBehaviour {
    public Sprite sprite;

    public void Collect() {
        // Here you can spawn a collection effect or play a sound, etc.
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

You could expand this to contain an `enum` of the different fruit types so you can react differently to them, or maybe make a `ScriptableObject` to hold the fruit's properties and gameplay effects, and hold a reference to that (ie. the [Type Object pattern](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html)).

Next we'll make a script that detects when we've collided with a collectable. Put this on your player character.

```
public class Collector : MonoBehaviour {

    // Here I assume you're using Unity 2020 or higher.
    public UnityEvent<Sprite> onCollect;
    // On older versions, declare public class CollectionEvent : UnityEvent<Sprite>{}
    // then make this a public CollectionEvent onCollect;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {

        // Ignore any trigger collisions that aren't collectables.
        if (!collider.TryGetComponent(out Collectable item))
            return;

        // If anyone is listening to our collection event,
        // tell them what we collected.
        if (onCollect != null) { onCollect.Invoke(item.sprite); }

        // Collect the item so it disappears.
        item.Collect();
    }
}
```

Lastly, we can have an inventory script that tracks what collectable(s) you're carrying and updates the UI accordingly.

```
public class PlayerInventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image itemSlot;    

    public void AddItemToInventory(Sprite sprite) {
        itemSlot.sprite = sprite;

        // Do other things you need to do with the collectable,
        // like applying gameplay effects or updating a counter.
    }
}
```

This can sit in your HUD. In the `Collector` script's Inspector, set the `onCollect` event to call the `PlayerInventory` script's `AddItemToInventory()` method. Or you can wire up this link after (re)spawning the player character with `collector.onCollect.AddListener()`.

If different items have different properties, then you might want to send the `Collectable` itself through this event instead of a `Sprite`, or a `CollectableType` data structure that has the properties you need.